# How to solve overflow flutter for an Collapsible AnimatedContainer?

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

I am trying to make a collapsible that opens all replies that can have a comment.

so I tried wrapping the AnimatedContainer with an Overflowbox and I didn't work out. the thing is that is expected to be solved and also is collapsible so I wasn't able to get so far both them working with constraints neither but default values like * double.infinity.

[image: Live]

```
AnimatedContainer(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          constraints: _constraints,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Reply_Comment(),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: I made a workaround "clipping" the reply with a list view with, physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() anyway I don't think is solved as expected.